# edit label in next view is very long

Tags: ios, swift

I have a little problem with my simple iOS app:
there is only 2 views, the first one send datas to the second (asynchronously then the second data is displayed before that the datas are downloaded, but when I print these data in the console, I can see that they are downloaded very fast.).

The problem is that I have to wait some seconds (between 10s and 20s) to see the `label` changes.
This problem only occurs with the `label`, for example I populate my `imageView` AFTER the `label` and the change on the image is instantly applied.

Here is the code of the 1st view:

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "profilevc")
        {
            let dvc = segue.destination as! ProfileController;
            dvc.data = self.loginField.text;
            _ = ftRemote(login: dvc.data, view: dvc);
        }
    }
```

and here is the function called in `ftRemote()` where the `label` are populate:

```swift
    private func populateView(user: UserProfile)
    {
        self.pfView.loginLabel.text = user.login;
        self.pfView.fullnameLabel.text = user.firstname! + " " + user.lastname!;
        self.pfView.phoneLabel.text = user.phone;
        self.pfView.walletLabel.text = "Wallet: " + String(Int(user.wallet!))
        self.pfView.correctionLabel.text = "Correction: " + String(Int(user.correctionPoints!))
        self.pfView.levelLabel.text = String(Float(user.level!))
        self.pfView.profilePicture.downloadedFrom(link: user.imageUrl!)
    }
```

Can someone explain this delay ?

Thanks

Comment: UI updates must be done on the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you perform your UI-related stuff in the main thread. Call your `populateView` like that:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // actions with you UI, e.g. populateView(...) call
}
```